# Specific frequency per samples

Tags: sql, date-arithmetic, word-frequency, postgresql-9.6

This is my table:

```
     chr  pos refalt
     ---------------
     chr1 123 AA
     chr1 123 AA
     chr1 123 AA
     chr1 123 AA
     chr1 123 AA
     chr1 123 AC
     chr1 123 AC
     chr1 123 AC
     chr2 456 TC
     chr3 789 GC
```

I need to calculate the specific frequency, I'll give you an example:

Each row is a patient so for "chr1 123 AA " there are 5 patients and for "chr1 123 AC" there are 3.

I want to know the frequency of A

The calc are:

```
13(A)
/16   , Because There are 13 people in "Chr1 123" who has A and in total they're 16 5XA (ref) 5XA(alt) + 3XA (ref) 3XC(alt)
```

For C:

```
3(C)/16 , Because only 3 people has C
```

How can I achieve this in SQL is it too complicated?

`Refalt` is a `varchar` column, so I need to split each value in order to get ref and alt.

I know is a bit complicated just ask me for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone of you who wants to know (Expecially biologists) how to achieve this:

```
select substring(refalt from 1 for 1),  
           count( substring(refalt from 1 for 1) )::numeric / 
           (select 2*count(*) from ft_variants where pos_chr like 'chr1 12783') as frequency_allele1
    from ft_variants
    where pos_chr like 'chr1 12783'
    group by refalt

union

select substring(refalt from 2 for 1),  
       count( substring(refalt from 2 for 1) )::numeric / 
       (select 2*count(*) from ft_variants where pos_chr like 'chr1 12783') as frequency_allele2
from ft_variants
where pos_chr like 'chr1 12783'
group by refalt;
```